# C++ Arrays and pointers calling types

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Just wanted to clear my doubt, i have two codes can anyone tell me what's the difference between them?

Both the codes are compiling without any error but the output of the second code is not correct.

first code:

```
#include "iostream.h"

using namespace std;

void func(int *ptr, int size) {


  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)

 {

 ptr[i] *= 2;

    cout << ptr[i] << endl;

  }

}

int main() {

 int arr[] = {6, 8, 9, 6, 9, 9};

  func(arr, 6);

  return 0;

}
```

output is :

> 12
>
> 16
>
> 18
>
> 12
>
> 18
>
> 18

second code :

```
#include "iostream.h"
using namespace std;

void func(int *ptr, int size) {

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

(*ptr++) *= 2;

    cout << (*ptr++) << endl;

  }

}

int main() {
  int arr[] = {6, 8, 9, 6, 9, 9};

  func(arr, 6);

  return 0;
}
```

output is :

> 8
>
> 6
>
> 9
>
> 0
>
> 0
>
> 0

Comment: A modern compiler may not necessarily provided `"iostream.h"`. That's a pre-standard header. For standard C++ include `<iostream>`, and qualify names from the standard library (like `std::cout`), or add `using` declarations and/or directives.

Comment: Don'tr spam tags. C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: Olaf,
sorry, sorry, I've typed c++ but i don't know how this, sorry again.

Comment: Margaret Bloom,
this is my first question on this site, sorry. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incremented the pointer twice in for loop . Accessing memory out of bound is Undefined Behavior. In your case you got 0 but the behavior is undefined.

**No difference except in second case you are incrementing the pointer twice.**

To get correct behavior

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    (*ptr) *= 2;
    cout << (*ptr++) << endl;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

from this part of the code remove one post increment for ptr

(*ptr++) *= 2;

```
    cout << (*ptr++) << endl;
```